# How to exclude nodes from Spark cluster job?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have a job in PySpark that uses sci-kit learn 0.16.1. Cluster management recently added a number of nodes that use sci-kit learn 0.17.1, and the API for an object changed. The necessary upgrade or downgrade will take a while so I'm looking how to exclude certain nodes while submitting my job. Is this possible and if so, where should I do it? On YARN or in the spark-submit action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check yarn-site.xml where you can configure nodes to be included or excluded from yarn cluster. E.g in https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml check "yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.include-path" and "yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.exclude-path" properties.